# PayPal SDK when adding client id I get error paypal is not defined

Tags: paypal

When using the `test` client-id shown below, everything works:

```
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>

    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: '77.44' // Can reference variables or functions. Example: `value: document.getElementById('...').value`
              }
            }]
          });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

            // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
            // var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            // element.innerHTML = '';
            // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if I change the query parameter client id from `test` to my sandbox id:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb-v444pg***79*^@business.example.com&currency=USD"></script>
```

I get a console error saying paypal is not defined. Why doesn't my id work?

Answer (score 0):

> client-id=sb-v444pg***79*^@business.example.com

That's not a client id, it's a sandbox account email.

Obtain a REST API client id from [My Apps & Credentials](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications). When you create a sandbox app you choose the account it's associated with.